# Как реализовать эффект "расщепления" объекта при столкновении?

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр

Хочу реализовать эффект как в этом видео: https://youtu.be/pX2ZZjPpfkY?t=94
Как видно, круг при столкновении со стенкой распадается на более мелкие окружности. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь материалы по этой теме. А ещё лучше, как правильно составить поисковый запрос на русском и английских языках?

Comment: Судя по видео, шар заменяется набором шариков поменьше, которым придается та же скорость, что была у оригинального. А затем поведение шариков рассчитывается с учетом столкновений между ними. Не думаю, что это можно описать одним поисковым запросом. Если вы объясните, что именно вам непонятно как сделать, возможно мы сможем помочь. Не знаете, как равномерно расставить маленькие шарики по площади большого? Не знаете, как физически правильно рассчитать столкновения? Вы используете какой-то физический движок, или хотите написать все это вручную?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо за наводку. Посидев, подумав, я понял, что мне не нужна физика как таковая. Нужно только чтобы объект распадался на более  мелкие объекты, что намного облегчает мне задачу.